# For Loop in SQL Server - is this the right logic?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to take transactional data and cleanse it to meet my analysis needs.  There are some limitations to how transactions are recorded into the database, and I am trying to get around those limitations.

When a customer places an order with more than 1 product, the transactional database doesn't link the multiple products together.  Each product will have a unique sales ID, but there is no way to group multiple sales ID into 1 order.  Here is a sample:

```
OrderID   MultOrderID   CustomerID  SalesDate   SalesTime   ProductID   ProductCost ShippingCost
6082346                 7661X0A     2012-06-12  959         105         99.99       7.95
6082347   5809812YY6Y   T891002     2012-06-12  1005        222         99.95       7.95
6082348   5809812YY6Z   T891002     2012-06-12  1005        273         22.95       1.00
6082349   5809812YY71   T891002     2012-06-12  1005        285         499.95      1.00
6082350   5809812YY72   T891002     2012-06-12  1005        172         49.95       1.00
6082351   5809812YY73   T891002     2012-06-12  1005        105         99.99       7.95
6082352   5809812YY74   X637251     2012-06-12  1010        285         499.95      7.95
6082353   5809812YY75   X637251     2012-06-12  1010        30          1024.99     1.00
6082354                 T512AT0     2012-06-12  1017        172         49.95       7.95
```

An additional limitation to this transaction system is that it can not ship more than 4 products together.  If the customer places an order for 5 products, 4 products are shipped together (and charged 1 shipping charge), the remaining product is shipped separately and charged another shipping charge (yes, the overall business wants to rebuild this entire legacy system....).

What I am trying to determine is the number of products shipped per order, and the aggregate product costs and shipping costs.

If you look at the last 4 characters of the MultOrderID, you'll see that it's sequential, YY6Y becomes YY6Z, then rolls over to YY71, YY72.  The logic is standardized - I know that if the CustomerID, SalesDate and SalesTime are the same, then I can pair off the products together.  What I don't know is HOW I can accomplish this.

I believe the way to accomplish this is to break out the orders by CustomerID, SalesDate and SalesTime.  Then, I get a `for-loop`, or something like that to cycle through the individual entries.  Then, I look for the last 4 characters of the MultOrderID and say - If 1,2 and 3 are the same, and the 4th character is after the 4th character of the previous order, then pair it together, up to 4 orders.  If the orderID is the 5th to 8th order in the range, then that's shipment 2, etc.

Can this be done in `SQL Server`?  If not in that, what should I write this in?  And is a `for-loop` what I should be using in this case?

Edit:  Here is the output I am trying to get to.  Keep in mind that after the 4th product was shipped, I need to restart the ordering (so, 6 products get broken into 2 shipments [4 products and 2 products], 9 products into 3 shipments [4, 4, and 1].

```
PRODUCTSSHIPPED SALESDATE   SALESTIME   CUSTOMERID  PRODUCTCOST SHIPPINGCOST
4               6/12/12         1005    T891002     672.8       10.95
1               6/12/12         1005    T891002     99.99       7.95
2               6/12/12         1010    X637251     1524.94     8.95
1               6/12/12         1017    T512AT0     49.95       7.95
1               6/12/12         959     7661X0A     99.99       7.95
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far - The reason I thought I needed a loop was that I need to create a new shipment after the 4 product.  I guess a `CASE` would work with enough logic, but will try that later.

Comment: Not sure if SO notifies when you update an answer, but I've updated mine - should be what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well from this statement it seems like you want this:

> What I am trying to determine is the number of products shipped per
>   order, and the aggregate product costs and shipping costs.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0e71/30

So I'm not sure what you mean by using a foreach loop?

UPDATE:

Got it working using a subquery and ceiling function

Updated the fiddle

FYI SQL is:

```
SELECT
SalesDate,
SalesTime,
CustomerID,
SUM(ProductCost),
SUM(ShippingCost)
FROM 

(
SELECT
       SalesDate,
       SalesTime,
       CustomerID,
       ProductCost,
       ShippingCost,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY salesdate, salestime, customerid ORDER BY CustomerID) as ProdNumber
FROM Orders
) as Summary
group by SalesDate, SalesTime, CustomerID, ceiling(ProdNumber / 4.0)
```

I used ROW_NUMBER to get a running count of products for each order, then made this a subquery so I could do the grouping. The grouping just used the number of products divided by 4 (as float) and uses the ceiling function to round up to the nearest int to get it grouping into 4

Comment: From reading it again it also looks like you would like to get the shipment number. This is also trivial using ROW_NUMBER - I'll edit the fiddle

Comment: When I get home, the wife is expecting me back, and she will castrate me :D

Comment: Thanks - This is the logic I originally followed, but it broke down due to the limit of 4 products per shipment and the fact that the MultiOrderID rolls over to a higher 3rd character.  I'll edit the question based off of what I looking for the output.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the number of orders for that customer/date/time in the NumOrders field. It uses my new favorite function, Row_Number:

```
SELECT [CUSTOMERID], [SALESDATE], [SALESTIME], MAX(NumOrders)
FROM (
    SELECT [CUSTOMERID], 
    [SALESDATE],
    [SALESTIME],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CUSTOMERID], [SALESDATE], [SALESTIME] ORDER BY [CUSTOMERID]) AS NumOrders
) t1
GROUP BY [CUSTOMERID], [SALESDATE], [SALESTIME]
```

Comment: And the short answer it to avoid looping wherever possible because it's very resource-intensive. SQL likes doing things to entire columns (set-based), not rows (row-based, or ReBAR, Row by Agonizing Row).

Comment: I wouldn't make a blanket statement like that. Prior to SQL Server 2012, a cursor was by far the fastest (*supported*) way to perform running totals calculations. Self-joins or subqueries (the set-based solution) are exponentially more expensive as the table gets larger.

Comment: And I'm not saying that I don't use cursors, they're just over-used by programmers who are used to that paradigm. How about, "Use them where needed but have other tools in your belt"?

Comment: That's different than "avoid looping wherever possible" :-)

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need a loop here. Usually its considered as a bad practice in sql, unless completly unavoidable. Can you assume that if an order is made by a user at the same datetime exactly it belongs to the same logical order (order group)?
Anyway, the whole problem can probably be solved using SQL server's [partition and over clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). Look at sample D there, i think its doing something close to what you need.

**EDIT**

The range clause is availibale only in sql 2012, however you can still use partioning and rownumber, and then group by ur results by using simple calculation (ROWNUMBER / 4) on the returned rownumber

Comment: Thanks.  I'm taking a look at the partition and over clauses now.  Will follow-up when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why a loop is needed at all..

```
Select count(*) as ProductsOnOrder, LEFT(CustomerID,4), as CID,
       SalesDate, SalesTime, sum(productCost), sum(ShippingCost)
FROM YOUR_TABLENAME
GROUP BY left(CustomerID,4), salesdate, salestime
```

What order number do you want to display? Min? Max? All of em? what?  same question on products do you want to list the products or just count them?

```
Select count(*) as ProductsOnOrder, LEFT(CustomerID,4), as CID,
       SalesDate, SalesTime, sum(productCost), sum(ShippingCost),
       min(orderID), Max(orderID)
FROM YOUR_TABLENAME
GROUP BY left(CustomerID,4), salesdate, salestime
```

Since you know orderID is sequential for each line on the order you could return min/max and subtract the two as well to get a count.

Comment: Subtracting MIN and MAX doesn't work. What if someone has deleted one of the orders? What if an insert failed and the transaction was rolled back? The identity value that *would* have been there is gone.

Comment: keyword being COULD.  it does assume that data has not been deleted.  my ACTUAL answer was doing a count and group by needed columns.